# How to find out which clipboard manager my system uses?

Tags: shell, terminal, clipboard

I am not sure if the clipboard manager works as that shell interpreter in the sense we select one and only one to use in an interactive login shell (i.e., the terminal). If so, I wonder how to find out which clipboard manager my system uses.

I want to manipulate my clipboard history from the terminal (e.g., add to clipboard the contents of a file). I need to know if my GUI uses xclip, xsel, or something else. I am on `GNU/Linux`.

Comment: In all likelihood, it doesn't use _any_. Usually, you're using some GUI, running on either X11 or  Wayland. X11 implements the clipboard functionality itself, and in the case of Wayland, it will be implemented by whatever implementation of Wayland you're running. Most distros don't install any additional "clipboard managers" by default. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @muru "What exactly are you looking for?" Manipulate my clipboard history from the terminal (e.g., add to clipboard the contents of a file). I need to know if my GUI uses `xclip`, `xsel`, or something else.

Comment: `xclip` and `xsel` point to the same thing, X11's clipboard. So your problem basically boils down to detecting whether you're on X11 (`xclip` or `xsel`) or Wayland (something else).

Comment: @muru X11......

Comment: If you are using a macOS, the commands are `bpcopy` and `bppaste`.

Comment: @xgqfrms GNU/Linux

Comment: @xgqfrms *`pbcopy` and `pbpaste` (swapped `p` and `b`)